# How to reduce overlap in scatterplot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I am plotting a scatter plot of the number of restaurant reviews in week_n vs. week_n+1 for one restaurant.

Since number of weekly review values are discrete and small in number, I have the following scatter plot:
[image]

The plot is organized as follows:

1> x-axis number of reviews for the restaurant in some week n, y-axis number of reviews in week n+1 (so a point (3,5) for some n and n+1 means that it got 3 reviews in week_n and 5 reviews in week_n+1 and if that point is red in color it means that the star rating in week n was below 3.5/5.0 stars)

2> color: if star rating of the review (float ranging from 0-5 in 0.5 increments) for week_n is below 3.5 make point color red else blue color.

3> The different shades are due to overlapping points (alpha=0.6) but the problem with this is that it doesn't show a cluster of points rather it just shows one point with a lighter shade if there are points overlapping (at least thats what I think I might be wrong)

I have tested for overlap and I know there are supposed to be 366 points in the plot but only 33 points show up because of overlap. My question is how can I make all the 366 points show up in the scatter plot?

One approach would be adding an extra dimension and visualizing 3-D plot but I would like to know if anyone has any suggestions to solve this problem using a 2-d plot? (the only thing I can think of is introducing a small amount of noise into each point value so they form cluster around each of the 33 points currently in the scatter plot)

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about making a circle larger if it represents multiple points at the same location?

Comment: The problem is that a red point might be covering a blue point and many other red points, I want to capture that relationship also but if I make the points bigger, only the top most point will be displayed with some size and its color will be the same. I won't have the blue point represented in the plot explicitly.

Comment: How about an array of pie charts?